# Custom Instance Store with WorkflowService hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, persistence, workflow-foundation

Can anyone help me with Custom InstanceStore (class derived from InstanceStore) for Workflow Foundation 4.5?

I want to enable it in my WF service from web.config. But I can write only **sqlWorkflowInstanceStore**  to behavior section.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides official custom instance store documentation on their website at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee829481(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It's right, but seems not complete. They described not all commands.